# how to make a button in Sprite kit for touchesBegan

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

basically for now I got TitleScene, where are present name of the my game and when tap anywhere on screen it jumps to GameScene, it looks something like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

SKScene *scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionUp duration:1.0f];
[self.view presentScene:scene transition:transition];
}
```

My question how can i change this method to button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe give your sprite a name of "button" so you know which one youre touching

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *touchedNode = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

        if (touchedNode && [touchedNode.name isEqual:@"button"]) {
            // your code here
        }
    }
}
```